# Convergence of Indicator function in weak*-topology

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $\omega_n$ and $\omega$ be measurable subsets of $[0,1]$. Also let indicator function $\chi_{\omega_n}$ converge to $\chi_{\omega}$ in weak*-topology on $L^\infty(0,1)$, that is
$$\int_0^1f(x)(\chi_{\omega_n}(x)-\chi_{\omega}(x))dx \to 0, \quad \forall f\in L^1(0,1).$$
What can we extract from this. Are we able to say for instance 
$$\int_0^1|\chi_{\omega_n}(x)-\chi_{\omega}(x)|^2dx \to 0.$$

Comment: Doesn't $\chi_{\omega_n} \to \chi_\omega$ weakly$^*$ in $L^\infty[0,1]$ actually mean $$\int_{[0,1]} f \chi_{\omega_n}  \to \int_{[0,1]} f \chi_{\omega}, \quad\forall f \in L^1[0,1]$$ i.e. $\int_{\omega_n} f \to \int_\omega f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment above there is no absolute value sign in the definition of weak convergence.

You should also note that $|\chi_{\omega_n}-\chi_{\omega}|^{2}=|\chi_{\omega_n}-\chi_{\omega}|=\chi_{\omega_n \setminus \omega}+\chi_{\omega \setminus \omega_n}$. To see that this tends to $0$ apply the hypothesis with $f=\chi _{\omega}$ and then with $f=\chi _{\omega^{c}}$. I will let you complete the proof. [Will give details if needed].

Comment: I get two limits $\chi_{\omega}(\chi_{\omega\backslash \omega_n}-\chi_{\omega_n\backslash \omega})\to 0$ and $\chi_{\omega^c}(\chi_{\omega\backslash \omega_n}-\chi_{\omega_n\backslash \omega})\to 0$. I don't know what I should do with them now?

Comment: You should get $m(\omega \cap \omega_n) \to m(\omega)$ and  $m( \omega_n \cap\omega^{c}) \to 0$ where $m$ is Lebesgue measure. Use the fact that $m(\omega_n \setminus \omega) =m(\omega_n)- m( \omega_n \cap \omega) \to 0$ because $ m(\omega_n)=m(\omega_n \setminus \omega) +m(\omega_n \cap \omega) $.